# Entity Framework generated classes not appearing in Data Sources wizard

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, datasource

I have successfully generated EF classes for a remote MySQL database, with a resulting `.edmx`object that contains the `Context` and table-associated C# classes.

I built the application and tried to add the EF classes as object data sources, but the wizard only displays the `Properties` namespace and its contents.

[image: DataSourceWizard]

The same happens when I tried writing a static property that uses the generated classes. The data source wizard doesn't display any other namespace.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's a bug in Visual Studio. I reverted to .NET framework 4.5.2 from 4.6 and the data sources reappeared.

Comment: I am experiencing the very same thing, but only in one solution. I have tried changing .NET versions as you suggest, but with no luck. I have also tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding the solution. This is very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Tried everything, even changed default namespace. On the and it was that, that my project build platform target was x64, after changing that to Any CPU,a after build namespaces and classes reappeared.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out I had written my classes inside my entity framework class.  It will let you do it and everything will work as normal, but these classes will not show up in the data source explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then I compiled my project and it worked. You can give this a try.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35317470)